# How can I display selectBox items in chips?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, chips

I want to display data in chips using selectBox, but I got a problem while displaying these items like this:

[image]

My TS:

```
selectedPointsForts: any[]=[];
listPointsForts: any[]=[];

 SelectPointsForts() {
    this.PointsFortsService.findAll().then((res) => {
      this.listPointsForts= res.map(function(obj: any) {
        return {
          value: {
            id: obj.id,
            name: obj.libelle
          },
          label: obj.libelle
        };
      });
    });
  }
```

My HTML:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="listPointsForts" [(ngModel)]=" selectedPointsForts" [selectionLimit]=3 [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'12em'}" [maxSelectedLabels]=2></p-multiSelect>
          <p>Selected Cars: </p>
          <p-chips [(ngModel)]=" selectedPointsForts"  > </p-chips>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem !

Answer (score 0):

You can place `pTemplate` in `<p-chips>` element to format the chip items' displayed output.

```
<p-chips [(ngModel)]="selectedPointsForts">
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    {{ item.id }} - {{ item.name }}
  </ng-template>
</p-chips>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1qmfg8?file=src/app/app.component.html)

> Output

[image]

---

### References

[Chips (Custom Content)](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/chips)

Comment: I got the cross on the word !! I mean the cross of the remove item on the label !! do u know what is the problem pls ?

Comment: Hi, do you mean the remove icon for the chip item? If yes, that is the default behavior for the chip item.

Comment: like this https://files.fm/thumb_show.php?i=bn7u3xqsq ! is there any solution?

Comment: This looks like CSS issue from your side. You may adjust the CSS with `p-chips-token` and `p-chips-token-label` classes. You may check out the [Styling section](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/chips).